# How do I convert this .htaccess snippet to Nginx rules?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, regex

I have this snippet of .htaccess coming from Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/u_pages/%1.php -f
RewriteRule .* u_pages/%1.php? [L]
```

Using the Winginx online converter I get the following:

```
location / {
  if ($request_filename ~ index\.php){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /u_pages/%1.php? break;
  }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

What I'm trying to achieve:

I have regular plain php-documents in the folder `/u_pages/` -- e.g. `123.php`, `444.php` etc.

I need each of these to have URLs on the following basis:

```
example.com/index.php?id=123
```

-where the file name (`123.php`) corresponds with the number after `id=` in the URL

Hoping someone can lend a hand. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: which software is beeing used?

Comment: Thank you!!
No software for these pages, they are just static pages. However, there is a Wordpress install on the domain as well, but it's not being used to display these pages. Can you help?

Comment: a php file is not static. So what are you trying to do? It looks for me like an enduser ehich in fwct would be not on topic for serverfault.com but may be asked on superuser.com or webmasters

Comment: Disregard the file extension -- might as well be .html -- still trying to rewrite the URLs on Nginx.

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840497/convert-htaccess-to-nginx

Comment: I've tried the online converter, if that's what you mean. Didn't work.